# Nested Structures memory allocation

Tags: c, struct

I saw several questions on this topic .But my query couldn't be resolved.Links:

[Structure memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299218/structure-memory-allocation),
[Allocating memory for nested structure pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293875/allocating-memory-for-nested-structure-pointer),[Understanding Nested Structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457275/understanding-nested-structures)

Basically Memory is allocated when we create the instance of a structure not when we define it. So what if i create an object of another structure in this structure i.e. make something like this :

```
struct a{
int c;
};

struct b
{
struct a obj;
};
```

is now memory given to `struct a` object when we declare it in `struct b`?.(We can also do it through pointer but what if we do like this ).

Comment: Since there is no instance of `b` yet, you can't have memory allocated for its members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `struct b` is also a (another) declaration, just the same as `struct a`.

No memory allocation happens here. It's there for compiler to know, should a variable be defined of this type, how much memory to be allocated. Just because a member of a structure is another structure, it does not mean memory has to be allocated there. Once you have a variable of the type, memory allocation will take place.

Only thing to notice here, the inner structure type must be declared before it is used as a member of the outer type.